# When/how does Linux create system users during startup?

Tags: users, root-filesystem

I'm trying to bring up a circuit board from NFS mounted root filesystem (Debian 10). When booting it reported error through serial port:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Create System Users.
See 'systemctl status systemd-sysusers.service' for details.
```

And this is the only error message printed out. I could not login (probably because no users have been created), so I couldn't run any commands to check the details.

The root file system should be good as the board could boot from it when it was in an SD card.

So how is the process "create system users" performed when Linux starts? What can be contributing to this error?

Answer (score 1):

During startup, systemd initializes all of the configured and enabled services.  It orders them based on their explicitly stated requirements as well as some other metrics.

In your case, Debian includes systemd with the systemd-sysusers service, which is defined in the file: **/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-users.service**.

The default contents of that service should be something like:

```
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1-or-later                                                                                                                                         #                                                                                                                                                                                     #  This file is part of systemd.                                                                                                                                                      #                                                                                                                                                                                     #  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it                                                                                                                 #  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by                                                                                                           #  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or                                                                                                                #  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Create System Users
Documentation=man:sysusers.d(5) man:systemd-sysusers.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
After=systemd-remount-fs.service
Before=sysinit.target shutdown.target systemd-update-done.service
ConditionNeedsUpdate=/etc

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=systemd-sysusers
TimeoutSec=90s

# Optionally, pick up a root password and shell for the root user from a
# credential passed to the service manager. This is useful for importing this
# data from nspawn's --set-credential= switch.
LoadCredential=passwd.hashed-password.root
LoadCredential=passwd.plaintext-password.root
LoadCredential=passwd.shell.root
```

The `ExecStart` line tells systemd what to run for this service.  In this case it will run **/usr/bin/systemd-sysusers** with no parameters.  Some of the output of that utility can be found in **/var/log/messages**.  In my case (CentOS 9 Stream), a successful run outputs:

```
Aug 15 10:11:26 MY-VM systemd-sysusers[257]: Suggested group ID 65534 for nobody already used.
Aug 15 10:11:26 MY-VM systemd-sysusers[257]: Creating group 'nobody' with GID 999.
Aug 15 10:11:26 MY-VM systemd-sysusers[257]: Creating group 'users' with GID 100.
Aug 15 10:11:26 MY-VM systemd-sysusers[257]: Creating group 'dbus' with GID 996.
Aug 15 10:11:26 MY-VM systemd-sysusers[257]: Creating user 'dbus' (System Message Bus) with UID 996 and GID 996.
Aug 15 10:11:28 MY-VM systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

When I searched for the error you got, the most likely causes listed were: inability to write to root drive/partition (disk full, permissions, mounted read-only, etc.) and misconfiguration or syntax error in one or more of: **/etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/gshadow, /etc/group**.

Notice, the systemd service unit file also lists the manual pages to read for its documentation.

Comment: Thank you @t0w0i7ne. I didn't find /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-users.service and /var/log/messages in the file system, but I did find the problem to be in permission set for NFS export. After setting it to rw the problem disappeared and I was able to get in.